# Search all products with attributes color & size REST API : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

How can I filter and get all products which has specific color or size REST API ?

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/performing-searches.html This is official document for rest api product filter

Comment: @DhavalSolanki : Have you tried for size and color ?